# Ruby on Rails: Passing a variable to a partial that can be of different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Note: Apologies if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find an answer. Warning: Newbie to RoR, the answer is probably incredibly obvious.

I have a partial, `_show_address_on_map`, which shows the location of a person on a map. However, this person can be an `@employee` or a `@client`, and can be called from the employee_addresses controller or the `client_addresses` controller. Depending on which of the two it is, some things need to be changed within the partial.

In `employee_addresses/show.html.erb` I call the partial with

```
<%= render :partial => ".../show_on_map", currentUser: @employee %>
```

In `client_addresses/show.html.erb` I call the partial with

```
<%= render :partial => ".../show_on_map", currentUser: @client %>
```

Now in the partial (`_show_address_on_map`) I try to do an if-statement on currentUser:

```
<% if currentUser.is_a?(Client) %>
    #do something with @client
<% else %>
    #do something with @employee
<% end %>
```

This gives me the error `"undefined local variable or method 'currentUser'"`

How do I correctly define currentUser, so that it can be either @employee or @client as described? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= render :partial => ".../show_on_map", locals: {current_user: @client}%>
```

:)

Also as a ruby/rails convention, use the under_score rather than camelCase

Comment: Aka `snake_case`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the camelCase as well!

Comment: Just to add to Ruslan's answer, the reason for the locals hash is to assign "locally scoped" variables to the template and thus you'll never do something like {@current_user: @client }  (Cant assign to an instance var).  Also, its important to note that because of Rails limitations on its rendering system you can't use certain methods to check the vars such as "defined? current_user" because these local vars passed to the template are assigned to a "local_assigns" hash.  Instead you must check the "local_assigns" hash.  Ex.  "if local_assigns.has_key? :current_user " .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:object` to send a data into the partial, and that will define a variable with the same name as the partial

```
<%= render :partial => ".../show_on_map", :object => @client %>
```

So in your partial, you can reference the `:object` send with the name of the partial `_show_address_on_map`, you can do something like this:

```
<% if show_address_on_map.is_a?(Client) %>
    #do something with @client
<% else %>
    #do something with @employee
<% end %>
```

And that will contain the @client sent in `:object`, so you can control what action do in the partial.